# How to redirect user to login screen completely instead of opening login screen in iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iframe, authentication

I have two page A and B.I have put an iframe on page A.I have one link on page A.By clicking on this link I open page B in iframe.
After session expire if I click on this link , a login screen appear in iframe but I just want to redirect user to login screen completely instead of iframe.

How to achieve that.

Thanks

Comment: redirect top frame to login page from page B?

Comment: how to redirect frame i have only one frame.

Comment: `window.top.location.href = "http://asd.com/login";`  from javascript

Comment: writing anything on page B doesn't make sense because when i click on link login screen appear in iframe after session expire.